# Checking if value in list. Returning within or outside loop?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python programming. I'd like some guidance as to the reason behind the output. I was just doing some exercise online and came across a problem which I could not understand. The code goes like this:

```
def dataset(data,n):    
    for value in data:
        if n == value:
            return True
        else:
            return False

print(dataset([1,5,8,3], 3))
print(dataset([1,5,8,3],-1))
```

The output would be `False, False` which is the incorrect answer.

After some tinkering, I found out the problem. The correct code is as follows:

```
def dataset(data,n):
    for value in data:
        if n == value:
            return True

    return False

print(dataset([1,5,8,3], 3))
print(dataset([1,5,8,3],-1))
```

The output is `True, False` which is the correct answer.

So my question is why the different output with just a different putting of the `return False`and `else: return False` ?

Comment: Returning after **all** iterations have completed is quite different from always returning during the first iteration.

Comment: You really just need `return n in data`. Loop is unnecessary

Comment: Three logicians walk into a bar :
* The bartender asks, "would all three of you like some beer?"
* The first one replies,"I don't know"
* The second one replies, "I don't know either"
* The third replies, "Yes all three of us would like a beer"

Answer (score 3):

I know the question has already been answered but as you're new to Python I thought I'd give you a little extra :-)

```
def dataset(data,n):
    return n in data
```

This will work. It simply checks if n is in the list or not and returns either `True` or `False`

Answer (score 2):

Your first answer stops after the first item, the false branch runs for each item, whereas the second only runs the false branch after all the items have been tried.

If you change the final code to this:

```
def dataset(data,n):
    print("checking", data, n)
    for value in data:
        print("trying", value)
        if n == value:
            print("Found")
            return True
    print("Giving up")
    return False

print(dataset([1,5,8,3], 3))
print(dataset([1,5,8,3],-1))
```

You can see it tries every item, as it outputs this:

```
('checking', [1, 5, 8, 3], 3)
('trying', 1)
('trying', 5)
('trying', 8)
('trying', 3)
Found
True
('checking', [1, 5, 8, 3], -1)
('trying', 1)
('trying', 5)
('trying', 8)
('trying', 3)
Giving up
False
```

Whereas the first code only tries the first item:

```
def dataset(data,n):
    print("checking", data, n)
    for value in data:
        print("trying", value)
        if n == value:
            print("Found")
            return True
        else:
            print("Giving up")
            return False

print(dataset([1,5,8,3], 3))
print(dataset([1,5,8,3],-1))
```

Which outputs:

```
('checking', [1, 5, 8, 3], 3)
('trying', 1)
Giving up
False
('checking', [1, 5, 8, 3], -1)
('trying', 1)
Giving up
False
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you are iterating through the list and then returning either True or False depending on whether the first item matches the input value. Since in your data the first element never matches the input, both return False.

In the second case, the function only returns if any list item matches the input. The loop iterates through all the elements until one is matched. If not, it returns False.

Answer (score 1):

When you have `else: return false` you program would return `False` whenever it encounters a element that is not `n` .
However,  if  you put it at the end of the function, the statement `return False` would only execute when none of the statement `n==data` that were previously executed are true because the function would no longer be executed after the `return` statement. When none of `n == data` is true, it means n in not in data.

Answer (score -1):

This loop

```
for value in data:
    if n == value:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Is logically equivalent to this one line

```
return n == data[0]
```

In other words, you've returned and exited the loop / function after the very first element

Your other solution, which is logically equivalent to `return n in data`, or `return any(n == x for x in data)` will iterate over the whole list, and give you the value after all values have been checked. (I think these two alternatives will short circuit when a match exists, though)